# Как в конце вместо запятой сделать точку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s = 'неделя, человек, путь, женщина, книга, путь, глаз, сторона, дом, путь.'
s = s.replace('а', '')
s = s.replace('у', '')
s = s.replace('о', '')
s = s.replace('ы', '')
s = s.replace('и', '')
s = s.replace('э', '')
s = s.replace('я', '')
s = s.replace('ю', '')
s = s.replace('ё', '')
s = s.replace('е', '')
s = s[:-1]
x = s.split()[-1]
s = s.replace(x, '').replace(', ,', ',')
print(s)
```

Мне выводит:

> ```
> ндл, члвк, жнщн, кнг, глз, стрн, дм,
> ```

Я хочу чтобы вывело:

> ```
> ндл, члвк, жнщн, кнг, глз, стрн, дм.
> ```

Укажите пожалуйста на мою ошибку и что я делаю не так?

Comment: вы вообще не учитесь? сегодня привел вам конкретный код блин в котором все работает, - ОТРЕЗАЕМ ТОЧКУ, ПРИМЕНЯЕМ ОСНОВНОЙ АЛГОРИТМ, ДОБАВЛЯЕМ ТОЧКУ

Comment: сегодня после нашего общения, я не писал алгоритм, а только щас начал делать, но я уже сам решил. Проблема что я не понимал, как работает ваш алгоритм и из-за этого делал сам и взял за основу вчерашнее решение. Возоможно у меня код больше чем у вас, но я понимаю как  работает

Comment: @Zhihar, понимаю, что может раздражать, но не нужно грубить :) Как писал один человек с стека, если видите вопрос и чувствуете, что можете сорваться на грубости, то отредактируйте вопрос, сделав его лучше для **следующего**, кто захочет помочь и пройдите мимо :)

Comment: @P1CA5S0, вы молодец, что смогли сами разобраться :) Можете привести пример кода (если его уже не привели ниже) в ответе?

Comment: добавил в свой ответ полное описание каждого шага, чтобы не смущало, что это в 1-2 строчки записано

Comment: Всё понятно, P1CA5SO плохо изучил строки в python и прикладывает мало усилий. Все потратили время на то, чтобы ему помочь. Всем +1, всем спасибо.

Comment: @AlTheOne я нашел ответ без использования других ресурсов. Проблема в моем опыте владения Python, не могу использовать свои знания на полную

Comment: @Zhihar спасибо вам за помощь и извините, что часто вас напрягал)

Comment: @gil9red ниже опубликовал свой ответ

Comment: да все нормально, просто показалось странным, что по сути один алгоритм перетирается :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну раз вы не извлекаете никакого опыта из предыдущих ответов...

Вот конкретно как делается ваш текущий

```
s = 'неделя, человек, путь, женщина, книга, путь, глаз, сторона, дом, путь.'

words = ''.join(letter for letter in s if letter not in 'аеёиоуыэюя')[:-1].split(", ")

s = ', '.join(word for word in words if word != words[-1]) + '.'

print(s)
```

1. из строки получить список букв без гласных

   ```
    arr = [letter for letter in s if letter not in 'аеёиоуыэюя']
   ```

т.е. пройти по всем буквам строки и в список добавить только те, которые не входят в список гласных

2. собрать список в строку через пустой разделитель

   ```
    string = ''.join(arr)
   ```
3. отрезать у строки последний символ (точку)

   ```
    string = string[:-1]
   ```

т.е. сделать срез строки от 0 символа до предпоследнего (`-1` от конца)

4. разбить строку на список слов через разделитель `,`

   ```
    words = string.split(', ')
   ```
5. удалить из списка все элементы равные последнему элементу (последнему слову)

последний элемент - `words[-1]`

удаление элементов через сбор нового списка в который такие элементы не входят

```
    new_words = [word for word in words if word != words[-1]]
```

или через фильтрацию с помощью функции filter

```
    new_words = filter(lambda word: word != words[-1], words)
```

6. собрать список в строку через разделитель `,`

   ```
    string = ', '.join(new_words)
   ```
7. добавить точку

   ```
    string = string + '.'
   ```

P.S.

касательно шага 5) - через фильтрацию:

```
s = ', '.join(filter(lambda word: word != words[-1], words)) + '.'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def main():
    s = 'неделя, человек, путь, женщина, книга, путь, глаз, сторона, дом, путь.'
    s = s.replace('а', '')
    s = s.replace('у', '')
    s = s.replace('о', '')
    s = s.replace('ы', '')
    s = s.replace('и', '')
    s = s.replace('э', '')
    s = s.replace('я', '')
    s = s.replace('ю', '')
    s = s.replace('ё', '')
    s = s.replace('е', '')
    s.rstrip(',')
    s = s[:-1]
    x = s.split()[-1]
    #s = s.replace(x, '').replace(', ,', ',')
    print(s.rstrip(','),'.',sep='')# Такой формат подойдет?
main()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я уже сам дал ответ на вопрос и опубликовал ниже. В вашем алгоритме выводит **ндл, члвк, жнщн, кнг, глз, стрн, дм, .**

Comment: В сообществе SO выражают благодарность проголосовав за предоставленный ответы. А для @Zhihar рекомендую зачесть как верный.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = 'неделя, человек, путь, женщина, книга, путь, глаз, сторона, дом, путь.'
s = s.replace('а', '')
s = s.replace('у', '')
s = s.replace('о', '')
s = s.replace('ы', '')
s = s.replace('и', '')
s = s.replace('э', '')
s = s.replace('я', '')
s = s.replace('ю', '')
s = s.replace('ё', '')
s = s.replace('е', '')
s = s[:-1]
x = s.split()[-1]
s = s.replace(x, '').replace(', ,', ',')
s = s[:-2]
print(s + '.')
```

Comment: Кст, иногда для обработки строк удобно использовать регулярные выражения. Например те удаления гласных можно было сделать в одну строку: `import re` + 
`s = 'неделя, человек, путь, женщина, книга, путь, глаз, сторона, дом, путь.'` + 
`s = re.sub('[ауоыиэяюёе]', '', s)`

Comment: я хотел как-то сократить код, но мне предлагали алгоритмы которые я не понимал. Вы щас предложили очень простой алгоритм для удаления гласных букв, спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста :) пользуйтесь :D

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter


def main():
    
    # Указываем ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТЬ символов одной стройкой...
    replace_chars = 'ауоыиэяюёе'
    target_string = 'неделя, человек, путь, женщина, книга, путь, глаз, сторона, дом, путь.'
    
    # Вычисляем количество каждого символа...
    counter = Counter(target_string)

    for replace_char in replace_chars:

        # Извлекаем количество символов `replace_char` в строке...
        count = counter.get(replace_char)
        if count is not None:
            
            # Если символ есть в строке, то убираем каждый...
            for i in range(count):
                target_string = target_string.replace(replace_char, '')

    print(target_string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```